# Почему токен не передается в метод?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def create
        @auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        @token = @auth["credentials"]["token"]
      end

  def self.get_events
    client = Google::APIClient.new
    client.authorization.access_token = @token
    service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
    result = client.execute(
        :api_method => service.events.list,
        :parameters => {
            :calendarId => 'primary',
            :maxResults => 10,
            :singleEvents => true,
            :orderBy => 'startTime',
            :timeMin => Time.now.iso8601 })
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    @events = result.data['items']
  end

SessionsController.get_events
```

Сначала идет аутентификация через google, а далее возвращаются созданные events с календаря юзера.
Но токен почему то не передается, хотя если все делать в методе create и выводить на view то ивенты отображаются 
Как передать токен в средину метода класа get_events?

Answer (score 1):

У вас метод create - это инстанс-метод (метод объекта), а get_events - это метод класса (def self.get_events). У них просто разный набор доступных данных. Метод класса просто не может добраться до переменных объекта и наоборот.